# New manifest with VersionOverrides makes app disappear in Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We put together a new manifest with two VersionOverrides sections, the outer one requiring Mailbox Set 1.4, and the inner one requiring 1.5.  Our app shows up in OWA, and Outlook 2013, but does not show up in Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019.  The validate-office-addin tool doesn't detect any problem with the manifest.  On the Outlook 2019 client we set up 'run time logging' as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest to see if it would log any 'installation' issues.  The file was created but the file size is 0.  The back-end is Exchange Server 2016.  If we go back to the earlier manifest we had, the app shows up again.  Is there a way to determine what is wrong with the manifest (or with Outlook)?

Comment: Can you provide us with the version numbers for Outlook 2016 and 2019?

Comment: 2019 MSO (16.0.10344.20008) 64-bit and 2016 MSO (16.0.4849.1000) 64-bit.

Comment: These version numbers are very recent. Can you please share your manifest so that we can analyze to see if there are any issues we can uncover?

Comment: I shared the manifest on OneDrive, please check it here: https://messageware-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/p/brianc/Eur-Dr9sdYZFlX7NKy7ISywBh08FYP2DZa63TVQw5cYdMQ

Comment: Thanks for sharing your manifest. We are now looking through it to see if we encounter any issues.

Comment: We noticed that you had duplicate resource strings named `paneReadSuperTipDescription` in your VersionOverrides 1.1 section. After removing that, the add-in shows up in Outlook. Can you make this change and try to see if it works for you?

Comment: That resource string was duplicated in two sections, we removed the duplicates from the manifest and Outlook shows the add-in.  It would be handy if the validation tools can detect this.  Thanks for resolving our issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook web add-in didn't show up in Outlook 2016 or Outlook 2019 because there was a duplicate resource string in the manifest file.  In my case, the duplicate looked like this (the 'DefaultValue' is not relevant):

```
    <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="misc text"/>
    <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="more misc text"/>
```